# Api.ai Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, mysql, json, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I am trying to store user inputs in MYSQL Database USING PHP so that I want to get JSON Data from my agent in api.ai(Dialogflow). I enabled Webhook fulfillment and placed a public api URL in the webhook tab.

But I am stuck on this error "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error"

I want to store user inputs and send custom messages from PHP code by webhook. I was searching for this solution in different places but couldn't find. Any help would be appreciated.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: If a server error occured, you can have a look at the server's error log to see why the error occured. This is part of the basic tools you should get to know as a developer

Comment: Don't post code through links to third party sites. Copy/paste all relevant code into the actual question. If that link gets removed/changes, the question will be useless for future visitors.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson for the suggestion and I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @NicoHaase this server error is not an issue raised only from the server side as you think, it depends on code also because all the parameters in JSON response must be sent as a response to the api.ai after generating a custom PHP message using webhook and so mainly all this was entirely about api.ai SDK. The part which I explained was a clear road and the people who are working on api.ai can understand it and can help me. Anyway thanks for it.

Comment: If you get a 500 server error, it's 100% raised by the code on the server. The _reason_ for the error might be anything, though (like missing params or what not). You still haven't told us what the error actually was (from your log). You also still haven't included your code. Your last comment is quite unclear though, did you actually solve the issue yourself?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I am still unable to fix it and here is what I am doing in my code (https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7v3xixt7nqr9jr/sample.png?dl=0) and here is my error (https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtarlzve4q0393d/sample%20webhook.png?dl=0) please help me with it.

Comment: Again, _"Don't post code through links to third party sites. Copy/paste all relevant code into the actual question."_ - It's pretty simple, all info about your code/error needs to be included _in the question itself_. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I only post the images there are no code files in it. I tried to paste the code but it was going beyond the characters limit and even it was not posting in the code format so I posted the images that's all.

Comment: You need to debug your code to narrow down the issue. Check where it goes wrong and post _all relevant_ code. Without code, the question is off topic. We're not mind readers. Please read the links I posted. I'm out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: 500 Internal Server Error means your code is wrong. Here is a sample code you can use to fix your code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
ob_start();
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$json = json_decode($requestBody, true);

$text = $json['result']['resolvedQuery'];
$response = json_encode(array(
        "source" => "webhook",
        "speech" => $text,
        "displayText" => $text,
        "contextOut" => array()
    ));

ob_end_clean();
echo $response;
?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @JacobCelestine thank you for the answer and it worked well.